# How should I solve for $y$ in the following exponential fraction

Tags: functions, exponential-function

How to solve for $y$ without complex solutions. That is how to algebraically find $y$ in the following equation:
$$x=\frac{2^{y}+2^{-y}}{2}$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $z=2^y$.

Your equation is then equivalent to
$$2x = z + \frac{1}{z} \iff z^2 - 2xz + 1 = 0.$$

By the Quadratic Formula, you get
$$z = \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 - 4}}{2} = x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 1}.$$

(Note that $x \geq 1$ by the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality.)

Therefore, you have
$$y = \log_{2}\bigg(x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\bigg)$$